# JSON Array convert to array of objects

Tags: c#, json

I have problem with JSON object. How do I convert an array:

```
[["age"],[12],[34],[53],[18],[32]]
```

to an array of object:

```
[{"age": 12},{"age":34},{"age":53},{"age":18},{"age":32}].
```

Comment: While this isn't exactly invalid JSON, it is also structured kind of backwards from how JSON is supposed to work. You'll likely have better luck **fixing** the source (because this really can be considered a _broken_ input) to either look like this `{"age":[12,34,53,18,32]}` or like this `[{"age", 12},{"age", 34}, {"age", 53}, {"age", 18}, {"age", 32}]`. Either of those could be considered an acceptable structure. What you were given is not.

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your problem (in JS, same logic should work on c#), having that the first array item is the key of the others:

```
var source = [["age"],[12],[34],[53],[18],[32]];
function convertToObjectArray(arr){
    var objArr = [];
    var prop = arr[0];
    for(var i = 1; i<arr.length;i++){
        objArr.push({[prop]: arr[i][0]});
    }
    return objArr;
}
console.log(convertToObjectArray(source));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var json = "[[\"age\",\"sex\"],[12,0],[18,1],[44,0],[56,1]]";

    var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);
    var newJArr = new JArray();
    for (var i = 1; i < jArr.Count; i++)
    {
        var jObj = new JObject();

        for (var j = 0; j < jArr[0].Count(); j++)
            jObj.Add((string)jArr[0][j], jArr[i][j]);

        newJArr.Add(jObj);
    }
    json=newJArr.ToString();
```

newJArr

```
[
  {
    "age": 12,
    "sex": 0
  },
  {
    "age": 18,
    "sex": 1
  },
  {
    "age": 44,
    "sex": 0
  },
  {
    "age": 56,
    "sex": 1
  }
]
```